Python re search replace not fidning a match
This is the input:
BEGIN^M
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job ( ^M
      job_name        => 'MY_JOB',^M
      job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',^M
      job_action      => 'begin
run_this_proc;
end;',^M
      start_date      => TO_TIMESTAMP( '2023-03-26 06:00:00.0 Europe/London' ),^M
      repeat_interval => 'null',^M
      schedule_name   => 'null',^M
      enabled         => FALSE,^M
      comments        => 'null' );^M
END;^M
/^M

I want to extract just job_name and job_action.
Here is my code:
   sfile = open( "the_file.sql" )
   filesrc = sfile.read()

   patt = re.compile ( r'^..*job_name  *=> \'(.*?)\',', re.MULTILINE )
   job_name = patt.sub( r'\g<1>', filesrc )

   patt = re.compile ( r"^..*job_action  *=\> '(.*)',.+start_date  + =\> .+$", re.MULTILINE )
   job_action = patt.sub( r'\g<1>', filesrc )

   print ("  Job Name:   " + job_name )
   print ("  Job Action: " + job_action )

In both cases I get:
  Job Name:   BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job ( 
MY_JOB
.
.

.

The thinking behind my regexs is:
r'^..*job_name  *=> \'(.*?)\',',
From the start search for job_name    => ' then grab just the region from that point up to the next ', .
r"^..*job_action  *=\> '(.*)',.+start_date  + =\> .+$"
From the start search for job_action   * => ' hen grab just the region from that point up to the next ', .

.* won't match across multiple lines unless you use re.DOTALL. So you're matching from the start of the line, not from the start of the string.

Why are you using sub() for this? Use re.search() to find the part that matches the regular expression.
